# Error at creating new Fragment on compileSdkVersion 22 on Android App : onAttach() method fails

Tags: android, android-fragments

I just use the menu to create new fragment and by default it's throwing an error with the fragment generated file, I did not add any code. The problem is in the **onAttach() method**

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

It says: "onAttach(android.app.Activity) in fragment cannot be applied to (android.content.Context)"

My imports on the fragment file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "license.j4ftech.com.mapevents"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

My gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "license.j4ftech.com.mapevents"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method onAttach(Context context) was introduced in API level 23. Your compile/target SDK version is 22 which is why the project cannot find the method definition. You can either switch back to using the old deprecated method onAttach(Activity a) or change the appcompat version to the latest (23.1.1) to be able to use the new method.

Use the latest support library:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

in your gradle file and set compileSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion to 23.

Comment: thanks, I was just updating to API 23 just in case .....I don't want deprecated methods...Thanks, I'll mark your answer as the correct one in 5 minutes

Comment: after the update is installed which values should I change from 22 to 23 on the gradle file??

Comment: I just edited my answer :). Also, remove support v4 dependency. You dont really need it as appcompat v7 adds it by default.